# Is it possible to use the Qt Designer in PyCharm with all the most recent versions?

Tags: pycharm, pyqt5, qt-creator, qt-designer, python-3.7

Is it possible to use the Qt Designer in PyCharm with all the most recent versions?

I use Python 3.7.0 and PyQt5 (5.11.2) in PyCharm and have downloaded the PyQt5Designer package (using PyCharm), but there seems to be no usable designer.exe file in the PyQt5 directories, and I cannot find any PyCharm functionality to start the designer either. Also, pyqt5-tools seems to be incompatible with Python 3.7.0, so that folder does not exist either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use PyQt5 with 3.7, and realized the same issue. I downgraded Python to 3.6, and all was good.. I'd recommend downgrading until a new version of PyQt is released to support 3.7.

Inside of the pyqt5-tools, after installation will have the designer.exe you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is already resolved. However, as there is no update and I found something working fine for me:
With Pycharm 2019.2 (64x) and Python 3.7 after installing pyqt5-tools (v5.11.3.1.4) one can find the 'designer.exe' under .../site-packages/pyqt5-tools/Qt/bin.

Note: I think this pyqt5-tools (v5.11.3.1.4) downgrades the PyQt5 to v5.12.1 if any upgraded version is already installed. However, it works fine!

cheers!